# Include VBscript class inside Classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I'm tring to implement LZW compression inside a classic asp script.
this is the LZW VBscript:
http://www.koders.com/asp/fid8C7ADB343C2D52BEC62BEFFCD05C2C3207C263AD.aspx?s=lzw#L3

However, I get into problems (including vb inside classic asp):

Microsoft VBScript compilation error '800a03ee'
Expected ')'
/_test/lzw_class.asp, line 109
Public Sub Compress_LZW_Static_Hash(aFileArray() As Byte)
-------------------------------------------------^

Is there a simple way to include vbscript inside asp?

Comment: Btw: if you have a classic asp LZW implementation function to compress strings, it will be a wonderful bonus :-)

Answer (score 3):

To "VBScriptify" that code someone has gone through it and made all the variables typeless variants by commenting out their type names, but they forgot to do so on line 109 (and a lot of other places too);

**Edit**; That class uses the CopyMem API so you can't port it to VBS. You will need to find an existing component that does compression or compile that class to a COM dll with VB6.

Answer (score 0):

For ZIP compression of files using ASP I use a DLL. Then whenever I need to use it I simply call it. In the old days we had to write our own DLL but today it sometimes fails. I have since found a free resource known as Xzip that has excellent performance enabbling me to create a file, save the file, ZIP it and send by email or provide a zipped download... on the fly using Classic ASP.

For the ZIP part see http://www.xstandard.com/en/documentation/xzip/